# Oracle return tree having all combinations

Tags: sql, oracle, tree

I need a query that will return all women within the group.

Example data table (Oracle 11g):

```
with t as (
  select 'K' as GROUP_NAME, 1 as ELEMENT_ID from dual
  union
  select 'K' as GROUP_NAME, 2 as ELEMENT_ID from dual
  union
  select 'K' as GROUP_NAME, 3 as ELEMENT_ID from dual
  union
  select 'L' as GROUP_NAME, 1 as ELEMENT_ID from dual
  union
  select 'L' as GROUP_NAME, 2 as ELEMENT_ID from dual
  union
  select 'L' as GROUP_NAME, 3 as ELEMENT_ID from dual
  union
  select 'P' as GROUP_NAME, 1 as ELEMENT_ID from dual
  union
  select 'P' as GROUP_NAME, 2 as ELEMENT_ID from dual
  union
  select 'P' as GROUP_NAME, 3 as ELEMENT_ID from dual
)
select * from t

K   1
K   2
K   3
L   1
L   2
L   3
P   1
P   2
P   3
```

I need to generate a tree with all the combinations without repeating them in groups (group K, L, P)

A tree must not contain a group of trees, i.e. there must not be a tree with such a branch: K1->L1->K2

```
K1
 +-- L1
   +-- P1
   +-- P2
   +-- P3
 +-- L2
   +-- P1
   +-- P2
   +-- P3
 +-- L3
   +-- P1
   +-- P2
   +-- P3
K2
 +-- L1
   +-- P1
   +-- P2
   +-- P3
 +-- L2
   +-- P1
   +-- P2
   +-- P3
 +-- L3
   +-- P1
   +-- P2
   +-- P3
K3
 +-- L1
   +-- P1
   +-- P2
   +-- P3
 +-- L2
   +-- P1
   +-- P2
   +-- P3
 +-- L3
   +-- P1
   +-- P2
   +-- P3
L1
  +-- K1
    +-- P1
    +-- P2
    +-- P3
  +-- K2
   ....
```

Comment: This is not how SO works.  Please make an attempt, and post what you have tried, problem,etc.

Comment: I had some ideas but all of them were too complicated and didn't work;)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(group_name || element_id,'-'),'-') FROM t
START WITH t.group_name = 'K'
CONNECT BY ( t.group_name = 'L' AND PRIOR t.group_name = 'K' ) OR ( t.group_name = 'P' 
AND PRIOR t.group_name = 'L');
```

> ```
> +-----------+
> | TREE_PATH |
> +-----------+
> | K1        |
> | K1-L1     |
> | K1-L1-P1  |
> | K1-L1-P2  |
> | K1-L1-P3  |
> | K1-L2     |
> | K1-L2-P1  |
> | K1-L2-P2  |
> | K1-L2-P3  |
> | K1-L3     |
> | K1-L3-P1  |
> | K1-L3-P2  |
> | K1-L3-P3  |
> | K2        |
> | K2-L1     |
> | K2-L1-P1  |
> | K2-L1-P2  |
> | K2-L1-P3  |
> | K2-L2     |
> | K2-L2-P1  |
> | K2-L2-P2  |
> | K2-L2-P3  |
> | K2-L3     |
> | K2-L3-P1  |
> | K2-L3-P2  |
> | K2-L3-P3  |
> | K3        |
> | K3-L1     |
> | K3-L1-P1  |
> | K3-L1-P2  |
> | K3-L1-P3  |
> | K3-L2     |
> | K3-L2-P1  |
> | K3-L2-P2  |
> | K3-L2-P3  |
> | K3-L3     |
> | K3-L3-P1  |
> | K3-L3-P2  |
> | K3-L3-P3  |
> +-----------+
> ```

If you didn't want a tree and just wanted all combinations, that would be a 'CROSS JOIN'. Like so:

```
select * from t k CROSS JOIN t l CROSS JOIN t p
where k.group_name = 'K'
AND l.group_name = 'L'
and p.group_name = 'P'
```

> ```
> +------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
> | GROUP_NAME | ELEMENT_ID | GROUP_NAME_1 | ELEMENT_ID_1 | GROUP_NAME_2 | ELEMENT_ID_2 |
> +------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
> | K          |          1 | L            |            1 | P            |            1 |
> | K          |          1 | L            |            1 | P            |            2 |
> | K          |          1 | L            |            1 | P            |            3 |
> | K          |          1 | L            |            2 | P            |            1 |
> | K          |          1 | L            |            2 | P            |            2 |
> | K          |          1 | L            |            2 | P            |            3 |
> | K          |          1 | L            |            3 | P            |            1 |
> | K          |          1 | L            |            3 | P            |            2 |
> | K          |          1 | L            |            3 | P            |            3 |
> | K          |          2 | L            |            1 | P            |            1 |
> | K          |          2 | L            |            1 | P            |            2 |
> | K          |          2 | L            |            1 | P            |            3 |
> | K          |          2 | L            |            2 | P            |            1 |
> | K          |          2 | L            |            2 | P            |            2 |
> | K          |          2 | L            |            2 | P            |            3 |
> | K          |          2 | L            |            3 | P            |            1 |
> | K          |          2 | L            |            3 | P            |            2 |
> | K          |          2 | L            |            3 | P            |            3 |
> | K          |          3 | L            |            1 | P            |            1 |
> | K          |          3 | L            |            1 | P            |            2 |
> | K          |          3 | L            |            1 | P            |            3 |
> | K          |          3 | L            |            2 | P            |            1 |
> | K          |          3 | L            |            2 | P            |            2 |
> | K          |          3 | L            |            2 | P            |            3 |
> | K          |          3 | L            |            3 | P            |            1 |
> | K          |          3 | L            |            3 | P            |            2 |
> | K          |          3 | L            |            3 | P            |            3 |
> +------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
> ```

Comment: The problem with the tree is that in the "connect by" clause you need to write all the possibilities, and in the cross such that it does not have a null value.

Comment: You wouldn't need to write all the possibilities if you provided logic as to why K is followed by L is followed by P.